Is it computationally feasible to find a basis for a multivariate polynomial ring quotient over a field?
I am working on a software project, based on Sagemath. I've found it would be nice (but not strictly necessary) to solve the following problem:

Given an (algebraically closed of characteristic zero, if necessary) infinite field $k$, a polynomial ring $k\langle A\rangle$ in some finite alphabet $A$ and a finite set $S$ of polynomials, decide questions of the following form:

Given a polynomial $f$ and a finite set $T$ of polynomials, wonder if $f$ is a linear combination of elements of $T$ modulo the ideal generated by $S$.


This is apropos finding a specific basis of $k\langle A\rangle$ and one of its subalgebras. The further details are unimportant: the mathematical problem is the one above. Truly; this is not an XY problem. I have seen this question but (1) I am confused by the answer (2) I am certainly not in the situation where $k\langle A\rangle/(S)$ is finite dimensional, so it likely doesn't apply.
And mathematically, it's fairly trivial; just find a basis of $k\langle A\rangle/(S)$ and then it's easy. But computationally I don't think it is trivial, since I want to use this computation to determine a basis of $k\langle A\rangle/(S)$ in the first place!
Sagemath, and any good computer package, can quite easily solve either of the following problems:

Given a vector space $V$ with a specified finite basis, determine if a finite set is linearly independent
Given a multivariate polynomial ring and an ideal in it, solve the ideal membership problem

Here, I'm more or less asking it to do both at the same time. When my field is not finite, I am essentially asking it run infinitely many ideal membership checks: is $f-t_1-2t_2\in (S)$, is $f-t_1-3t_2\in (S)$, ... when, say, $T=\{t_1,t_2\}$ and I have lazily given two simple linear combinations as examples.
I'm none too experienced with Groebner bases and computational mathematics more generally, so I'm hoping someone here might know some bizarre trick to help me here. My hunch is that this is 'undecidable', but I would love to be wrong (I've also been frazzled and working on other things, so I leave open the possibility I've missed something easy).

Gröbner basis was correct. It will always end up computing a basis for the ideal. However time complexity is not very favorable. Note that basis and computation time may, in some cases, depend heavily on the monomial order.

@LutzLehmann I don't mean to look for a basis of the ideal

But the set of leading monomials of the Gröbner basis bounds (in the monomial order) the set of monomials that form a basis of the remainder class ring.

This is not undecidable, but the ideal membership is involved, it is computationally expensive. In fact, ideal membership is a special case, which makes the problem EXPSPACE-complete.
The quotient algebra $k[A]/(S)$ always has a basis consisting of (cosets of) monomials. More specifically, one takes a Gröbner basis of $(S)$ and the basis of $k[A]/(S)$ as a vector space consists of all monomials which are not divisible by a leading monomial of any element of a Gröebner basis.
To represent an element of $k[A]/(S)$ in this basis, we use the multivariate division algorithm with a Gröbner basis (see for example Cox,Little,O'Shea "Ideals, Varieties, Algorithms", §2.3,§2.6).
In Sagemath, one can use the method reduce of the ideal, so you can reduce each of the polynomials involved using something like
I = ideal(S)
f = I.reduce(f)
T = [I.reduce(t) for t in T]

and then solve the linear algebraic problem without worrying about ideals.

Thanks! I'm guessing a proof of your claim that the monomials indivisible by a leading one in a Groebner basis (and I assume "leading" should be w.r.t. the same order used to compute the Groebner basis) can also be found in "Ideals, Varieties, Algorithms". This is great news, I wasn't aware of this property of Groebner bases

Do you know with certainty that Sage implements this same division, that it reduces elements into the basis you proposed?

Yes
Admittedly, they only document that this is a normal form, but they do reduce to this basis.

@FShrike The proof of that property is simple: first, the division algorithm can reduce any element to a linear combination of such monomials, which shows that they span the quotient vector space.  On the other hand, any nontrivial linear combination of such monomials has leading term corresponding to the largest monomial with nonzero coefficient, so by the Groebner basis property, that combination is not in the ideal, showing linear independence.

Hi, does this work fine regardless of which monomial ordering convention is used to compute the Groebner basis?

Yes. The normal form depends on the ordering, of course, but as long as we use the same ordering for all polynomials involved, everything should work fine.
